# chrome dev tools doesn't show repetitive css properties in stable release

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

it's useful when developing to know all the css properties implemented for specific element but chrome stable release doesn't do that,
here is and example, the body element have gradient background but of course to implement this on all the browsers you have to do this

```
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 500, center center, 1400, from(transparent), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6))) white;
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(farthest-side, transparent 90%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 150%) white;
background:    -moz-radial-gradient(farthest-side, transparent 90%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 150%) white;
background:     -ms-radial-gradient(farthest-side, transparent 90%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 150%) white;
background:      -o-radial-gradient(farthest-side, transparent 90%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 150%) white;
background: radial-gradient(farthest-side, transparent 90%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 150%) white;
```

like [here](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html)

so when you inspect the body element in chrome stable release you get this
[image]

but in the canary you get this
[image]

so is there away to enable the stable release to show all the repetitive properties?

Comment: This is not what I get in my stable Chrome...I can see from your screenshot that you installed some extension that works with dev tools. Did you tried to disabled them and see what happen?

Comment: the same thing- and this extensions are installed on the canary and stable release and the canary release show all the repetitive properties while the stable release doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Chrome simply ignore the properties that are not targeted to him ... it's normal. If you want to test / debug your code for other properties (with other vendor prefix) you should test / debug them with the right browser : chrome dev tools are not made for this.

Comment: so why the canary release behave in different way and show all the repetitive properties